# Struct string not saving to storage from mapping

Tags: solidity, storage, struct

Good morning guys,

I would like to get some help with some declaration that I am doing in my solidity contract, basically I want to have some data on my registry from a user, such as if it is admin, category and also an alias.

I can declare both the `isAmin` and `rol` with other functions but when minting and giving an alias to the `User` struct it does not keep persistent, this is the function where I declare it and the relevant part of the code:

```
 struct User {
        bool isAdmin;
        Category rol;
        string usrAlias;
    }
 enum Category {
        CLIENT,
        COMPANY,
        TEAM
    }

   mapping(address => User) public user;


function mintAlias(
        address to,
        string memory usrAlias,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) external onlyMintManager {
        uint256 newId = totalSupply() + 1;

        string storage mailAlias = usrAlias;

        user[to].emailAlias = usrAlias;

        _safeMint(to, newId);

        emit AliasMinted(to, tokenId, usrAlias);
    }

function giveUserRol(address _user, Category category) public onlyAdmin {
        user[_user].rol = category;

        emit ChangedUserRol(msg.sender, _user, category);
    }
```

Ok after calling the `MintAias()` I request the user with ethers like `const [, , alias] = await contract.user(<user>.address)` and I get an empty string meanwhile when doing `const [, rol, ] = await contract.user(<user>.address)` I get the proper rol for each user.

I saw this old conversation about something similar but it was never answered:

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/381

I would love some help might be something that I am not noticing because I can not store them either with a mapping...